# Using Python Regex to textually analyze meeting minutes: "who said what"

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, split

I'm trying to textually analyze "who said what" in FOMC meetings. I have these PDFs of the meeting minutes converted into text.

My current plan is to use regex to split the file on the names (always capitalized) and keep the delimiters.

```
names = re.findall("\s\n{2,}[A-Z]{2,}\.*\s*[A-Z]{2,}\.\d*\s",text)
speech = re.split("\s\n{2,}[A-Z]{2,}\.*\s*[A-Z]{2,}\.\d*\s",text)
```

And then I write these lists into a CSV with two columns: names, speech.

Is seems like a really inefficient method. Is there a better way to do this?

Sample of minutes:

\n\nCHAIRMAN BERNANKE.  Good afternoon, everybody. 
 \n\nPARTICIPANTS.  Good afternoon.
 \n\nCHAIRMAN BERNANKE.  We need a motion to close our meeting.
 \n\nMR. KOHN.  So moved.
 \n\nCHAIRMAN BERNANKE.  Thank you.  Our meeting today and tomorrow follows the \n\nbasic sequence we’ve been having recently, but with an important addition, which is that we \n\nhave a staff presentation on inflation dynamics.  We need about two hours for that presentation, I \n\nunderstand, and we’ve thought about it and decided to put it at the end of the meeting so we \n\nwould have plenty of time to complete our policy decision.  But I hope that people will pay \n\nattention to the time and make sure we have enough time tomorrow to give appropriate attention \n\n \nto the presentation. \n\nIn that spirit, why don’t we start directly?  Mr. Sack.
 \n\n\nMR. SACK.  Since the last FOMC meeting, financial conditions have generally \n\n\nbecome more supportive of economic growth.

Comment: You could at least use a simpler regex. For example, you can match the names just by capturing everything that occurs between any double newline and a .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex could be much simpler:

```
re.split("([A-Z \.]+\.)",text)
```

And then your code could just be:

```
data = list(filter(None, [s.strip() for s in re.split("([A-Z \.]+\.)",text)]))
```

Then you can do:

```
names = data[0:][::2]
speech = data[1:][::2]
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/OpenLooseWeblogsoftware)